# How to display metric value on sonarqube dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Is it possible to display the metrics value on the sonarqube dashboard directly through html.erb file? 
One of my metric is Rank

Can I just write `<%= format_measure('Rank') %>` to display on the dashboard?
This donot print anything on dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format_measure` is indeed the correct helper to print out the value of a metric in a widget.

There can be several reasons why you don't see the measure for that metric:

- you haven't run any analysis on the project, in which case your plugin haven't pushed the measure for that metric yet
- your plugin does not push correctly measure for that metric

  - Ex.: it pushes measures at file level but not at project level

In any case, you can take a look at [our sample plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin/) to learn more, and more specifically at the [widget template](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin/src/main/resources/example/example_widget.html.erb).

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how can I make histogram using my own metrics ? Or how can I access each element of rank .. rank is an array